# Finding an Hierarchy of row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to find the logic for below question in SQL Server.

I have a table like below.

```
id    ParentID 
---------------
 1       NULL      
 2       NULL 
 3       1 
 4       2 
 5       3 
 6       5
```

I need a query which will return hierarchy of a row, like this:

```
Hierarchy   id    ParentID 
----------------------------
 1           1       NULL     
 1           2       NULL
 2           3       1
 2           4       2
 3           5       3
 4           6       5
```

I will explain the hierarchy:

1. For any row if `ParentId` is null then `Hierarchy` will be 1
2. Any row if `ParentId` is not null and `ParentId`'s `ParentId` is null then 2
3. Any row if `ParentId` is not null, `ParentId`'s `ParentId` is not null and next `ParentId`'s `ParentId` is null then 3
4. And it goes on

How can write the query for this logic.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a recursive query:

*(in the below example your initial table data is stored in #a):*

```
;With DATA AS (
    SELECT   1 as hierarchy
            ,Id 
            ,parentid
    from    #a
    where   parentid is null 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   Data.Hierarchy + 1
            ,a.id
            ,a.parentid
    FROM    #a a
                INNER JOIN DATA
                    ON      Data.id = a.parentid
)
SELECT  *
FROM    DATA
ORDER BY hierarchy, Id
```